# [Highschool Algebra]Mensuration including sector area.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, area

[image]

> The mark scheme says the answer is $5.68$. Can anyone explain me step by step how this was found?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't find this value. They do ask for the value ofthe coefficient $k$ for the shape which  looks like a keyhole?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pQvk3uH thats the answer to the question. Hope that helps

Comment: But there are two answers. I think the problem is *what* is asked?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont follow. Are you saying that you got the answer that is on the left hand side of the answer but you did not get the 5.68?

Comment: As far as I understand the answer, I obtain what's on the right side,

Comment: [Image is not a shortcut for not typing the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305).  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- area of circle sector: $\frac{3}{4}\pi x^2$
- area of triangle: $\frac{1}{2}x^2$
- area of rectangle: $2x\sqrt{2x^2} = 2\sqrt{2}x^2$
- area of whole shape: $kx^2$
  $$(\frac{3}{4}\pi + \frac{1}{2} + 2\sqrt{2})x^2 \approx 5.68x^2$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand completely however can you please tell me how you did the calculation for the "area of rectangle" statement of your answer. 2x√2x^2 turns into 2√2x^2. How is this done?

Comment: The shorter side of the rectangle is the hypothenuse of the right triangle on top: shorter side $= \sqrt{x^2+x^2} = \sqrt{2x^2} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2}\stackrel{x>0}{=}\sqrt{2}x$. Now, multiply by the larger side $2x$.

Answer (score 0):

For the circular part you get $$ (3/4) \pi x^2 $$

For the triangle you get $$ (1/2)  x^2 $$ because it is a right triangle.

For the rectangle you get $$ (2\sqrt 2) x^2$$

So the total is $$(3/4 \pi+1/2+\frac  12+2\sqrt 2)x^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

For me, the circular sector corresponds to an angle of $\theta=\frac{3\pi}2$ (in radians). The formula for the area of a circular sector with angle $\theta$ is
$$\mathcal A_S=\frac12\theta \mkern2mu r^2.$$
(note that, for a full circle, $\theta=2\pi$, and you obtain what's expected: $\pi r^2$.)

As to the rectangle, you have to find its width. The triangle is an isosceles right triangle, its area is $\mathcal A_T=\frac12 x^2$, and its legs have length $x$, so by Pythagoras, its hypotenuse has length $\sqrt 2x$ . Finally the area of the rectangle is
$$\mathcal A_R=2\sqrt2 x^2,$$
so that in all, the area of the shape is
$$\mathcal A=\mathcal A_S+\mathcal A_T+\mathcal A_R=\frac{3\pi}4x^2+\frac12x^2+2\sqrt2 x^2$$
and $\quad k= \dfrac{3\pi}4+1+2\sqrt2\approx5.685$.